# Tableau desktop : how to create a filter on a part of a view

Tags: filter, tableau-api, desktop

I'm working with Tableau desktop.
I created a view with 2 graphics (same Axe Y), and I'd like to create a filter on the values of the first graphic only, without affecting the second graphic.
Is it possible ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: when you refer to "view with 2 graphics", you mean a dashboard with 2 worksheets?

Comment: hello,
the 2 graphics are in the same worksheet
I tried the function FIXED, but I have other filters and parameters which doesn't work any more

Comment: please, attach a screnshot, otherwise it is quite hard fully understanding what your goal is... as far I understand you may want to use 2 calculated fields for your measures having one of them related to the filter... depending whether your filter should be static or dynamic, you may want to use a parameter